# Jenkins and Git hanging on sync from bitbucket due to passphrase for id_rsa

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm pushing an ASP WebApi project to BitBucket. I have Jenkins setup to watch the repository of BitBucket.

When I trigger a build manually, it hangs for 10 minutes then times out. If I log into my VM and run the command manually:

```
git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It then prompts me to enter a passphrase for key /c/Users/webmaster/.ssh/id_rsa

I'm assuming this is why the build is hanging, since the process is is prompting for a password.

I've added the public rsa key to my bitbucket, but I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to generate key with empty passphrase? [It seems](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20879) Jenkins doesn't support SSH keys which require a passphrase yet.